# How to access a folder above a running jar

Tags: java, image, file, cross-platform, relative-path

Background:
i have a running .jar called `main.jar` in the location `C:\Program Files\folder\files\bin\main.jar` on Windows. I also have a properties file in the same location named `p.properties`. At the same time, i have a .png file at `C:\Program Files\folder\files\graphic\img.png`.

My Question:
how do i access the p.properties file from the .jar, compared to accessing the img.png file. i believe that i can just use `new File("p.properties");` from the .jar, but how would i access the img file? it is in a different folder, and i've tried `new File("graphic/img.png");` but that didnt work. how would i do this? and am i correct in accessing the properties file?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What package name do you use in the class on which you try to access the file? If you don't have any package(so it's the default one), then you will access the `.png` file using `new File("../graphic/img.png"`.

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you need to have data related to code, put the data *in* the jar, and use Class.getResourceAsStream to reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a relative path, `..`  refers to the parent directory. For example,

```
new File("../graphic/img.png");
```

By the way, these paths are relative to the program's current working directory, and it might not be the path where your .jar file is located. To find the path where your jar is located you can use:

```
File jarFilePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain()
                             .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Comment: Yes, but with the same caveat as on Windows: the program has to be started with `bin` as its working directory. It would be safer to search for files relative to where the .jar is located.